# INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS : and must be a Primary Key : Mysql query

Tags: mysql

I've added a question on most of the solved problem with regards to COLUMN_NAME searching but didn't get any feedback yet.

How to do a query that goes like this:

> I want to see all the tables that has a column name of 'Type_ID' and
>   **must be a Primary key** to the table.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM information_schema.key_column_usage WHERE constraint_name = 'PRIMARY' AND column_name = 'Type_ID'` may work - do you want it where it's the ONLY column in the key, or you don't care as long as it's part of a primary key?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT table_schema, table_name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE (table_schema, column_name, constraint_name) 
    = ('mydatabase', 'Type_ID', 'PRIMARY');
```

Comment: +1 faster than me :-) I haven't seen that `WHERE` clause style before - looks interesting.

Comment: @dash I've added: AND TABLE_SCHEMA='<database name>' condition to search only on specific database but shows 0 (zero) row result. How will I add now the db name? thanks

Comment: @Raf if you do SELECT * as per my comment, what values are currently in the TABLE_SCHEMA column?

Comment: I've edited the above query to include a test for schema.  I'm not sure, but the schema name might be case-sensitive.

Comment: @dash, the tuple-comparison syntax is standard SQL, and it should be supported by any RDBMS worth its name.

Comment: @BillKarwin Thanks! Once you know what it's called it is easy to find. SQL Server (2005, 2008) doesn't appear to support it though :-/

Comment: @dash, yes, it seems it works in Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc. but not in Microsoft SQL Server or SQLite.  Maybe in some future release.

Comment: What are the odds that the constraint_name is going to be called 'PRIMARY'? There's no reason it would be called that.
Edit: the table that should be inspected for this is  information_schema.table_constraints and not the table mentioned above

Comment: @Amalgovinus, This question is tagged for MySQL, and in MySQL the primary key constraint is always called 'PRIMARY'. You can't make a primary key with any other constraint name. Also, the question was finding tables with a specific column name in the primary key, but INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS doesn't name the columns of the constraint.